# Looking for word describing a person who is always really quick at looking things up

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I was wondering if there is a word to describe a person who always is really quick at looking things up on etc. his phone.

E.g when you just can't remember the characters name in the film you just saw and this guy quickly pulls his phone out and looks it up.

I am looking for an adjective to fit: I was not sure about the meaning of the word, but the quick-lookup-guy quickly found the answer.

Comment: 'search-guru' would be my coined term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The skill is known as [Google-fu](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=google-fu), and is a [noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu).

So although you can't use it as a straight adjective (ie 'he is Google-fu'), you can say 'his Google-fu is very impressive'.

In terms of your sample sentence, you could have:

> I was not sure about the meaning of the word, but the Google-fu master
>   quickly found the answer.

Comment: You can even grade it using other martial arts terminology [though best stick to the ones most people know.] From white belt to black belt, or even 7th dan google-fu.

Answer (score 1):

I can't come up with a word that fits the bill. Depending on the context in which you wish to use the term, perhaps you could coin one along the lines of: *Googleholic,* *Googlemaniac,* *Wiki-it-all*, *Net-ref-nut* etc.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure about the meaning of the word, but my ***google-master*** friend quickly found the answer with his phone.

I can't give you a definition or a source because I made it up.

Answer (score -3):

Inquisitive 
Fidgety
Animated 
Detail obsessed /OCD
Impolite
Gullible?[image]

Comment: So, is this one answer or eight?  (The question asks for a single word.)

Comment: Both. It's options for the one James is looking for

Comment: ***None*** of those are even close to what OP is looking for.